# Package Keycal Error: Backround Undefined

Tags: captions, lstlisting

I am at the moment completely clueless as to how to get rid of the error in the following:

```
\documentclass[paper=a4,fontsize=12pt,twoside]{scrreprt}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{listings}
\lstdefinestyle{C++}
{
 keywordstyle =  \bfseries\color{Blue},
 language=C++,
 columns=flexible, 
 basicstyle=\footnotesize\ttfamily,
 commentstyle=\color{codegreen}\ttfamily,
 numbers=left,
 showstringspaces=false,
 breaklines=true,
 backround=white
}
\usepackage{caption} % Abbildungslegenden
\captionsetup{format=hang, justification=raggedright}
\begin{document}
\begin{lstlisting}[style=C++, caption= Schreiben der Daten der letzten             60 Sekunden in die Listen, captionpos=b]
 a=5;
\end{lstlisting}
\end{document}
```

> ```
> Error Log: ! Package keyval Error: backround undefined.
> ```
>
> See the keyval package documentation for explanation. Type  H 
>   for immediate help.  ...
>                                                      l.270 ... 60 Sekunden in die Listen, captionpos=b]
>                                                      Try typing    to proceed. If that doesn't work, type  X   to quit.
>
> Package babel Info: Redefining ngerman shorthand "| (babel)
>   in language  on input line 270. Package babel Info: Redefining ngerman
>   shorthand "~ (babel)             in language  on input line 270.
>   Package babel Info: Redefining ngerman shorthand "| (babel)
>   in language  on input line 270. Package babel Info: Redefining ngerman
>   shorthand "~ (babel)             in language  on input line 270. [22]
>   LaTeX Font Info:    Try loading font information for T1+fvm on input
>   line 270.  (/usr/local/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/tex/latex/bera/t1fvm.fd
>   File: t1fvm.fd 2004/09/07 scalable font definitions for T1/fvm. )
>   LaTeX Font Info:    Font shape `T1/fvm/bx/n' in size <10> not
>   available (Font)              Font shape`T1/fvm/b/n' tried instead on
>   input line 271.

Comment: Texmaker on mac

Comment: Sorry for the German, I have some trouble finding out why texmaker gives me this error.

Comment: Would be better if you could also include the error output. The above is only the tex file.

Comment: @SimonB, just on a side note, you can format your question **in future** by following [this](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting). I did it for this question.

Comment: The error message means simply that the option `backround` does not exist. In the `listings` documentation I found only `backgroundcolor`.

Comment: @campa Thanks that was it!